# Random integer generating in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there any inbuilt function in Haskell that gives a random number in a range like

x = random(a,b) such that x gives an integer lies between a and b .

a <= x <= b

And some functions in Haskell gives same number when I executes multiple times .

Thank you in advance :) .

Answer (score 3):

There is one called `randomR` in `System.Random`. If we look at it's type signature:

```
randomR :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => (a, a) -> g -> (a, g)
```

and specialise it to Integer we get

```
randomR :: (RandomGen g) => (Integer, Integer) -> g -> (Integer, g)
```

so this is a function that given a low and hi, and a random number generator returns a random Integer and a new random generator. This makes sense, since Haskell is a pure language, calling randomR with the same random generator will always return the same result.

So how can we use this in a program?, We'll need a random number generator to start with. The easiest way is to use either `mkStdGen :: Int -> StdGen` to create a random number generator from a seed, or to use `newStdGen :: IO StdGen` to return the system random number generator.